# If you have 100% trust in hashem, nothing can happen to you

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, faith-bitachon-emunah

I’ve heard that the more trust you have in Hashem, the more Hashem does for you. For example if you have a high level of Emunah in Hashem that your kids will be handsome, your kids wills come out handsome. I’m curious where the speaker got this from. Cite sources please?

Comment: This seems pretty demonstrably false.

Comment: This is along the same lines as “if you daven to Hashem, your tefillos will always be answered,” also demonstrably false. The correct approach is having 100% emunah that everything Hashem does is for your own good, even when it seems bad.

Comment: @DoubleAA Although I agree with you, people may argue that in those many cases where this did not prove true, the person did not have enough true emuna.

Comment: After researching I found a source in Tehillim. “Cast your burden on the Lord, and He will bear you; He shall never allow a righteous man to falter” This could be the source the speaker was referring to?

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam in Moreh Nevuchim 3/51 s.v. והנה נגלה אלי, and the Maharal in Nesivos Olam in Nesiv HaBitachon in the first paragraph, are two of the many sources for this.

However, the Chazon Ish in Emunah u'Bitachon seems to question the obligation to think this way, since this good thing your trusting will happen was not heard from a Navi.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin We can't do the Heavenly math, you will only be revealed the true answers when you finish the game.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Getting more hashgachah doesn't mean getting things your way. The Rambam's -- and most rishonim's -- understanding of hashgachah as something earned actually mitigates the Chazon Ish's understanding of bitachon. According to the CI, it's coming to terms with what happens to you because you know it's part of Hashem's Plan. According to the Rambam (other rishonim have other means of earning hashgachah), you can't be sure of that. It could be that the person who is unhappy with their fate simply didn't earn intervention. And the event in question was blind fate / nature or luck.

Comment: The Rambam talks about people earning the chance to have a life in which Hashem plans what is best for them. Not getting what they want. The CI defines bitachon as faith in that plan, also, not faith in getting the fate I want. So, the Rambam's need to earn Providence limits the CI's bitachon that believes and reacts to everything as thought it's Providence.

Comment: Another thing that often gets conflated with hashgachah is reward-and-punishment. G-d's Plan includes Justice. But it also includes Mercy. And, delaying Justice to get other objectives met. And... and so much "ands", that trying to make sense of the world is often impossible. But that could all be hashgachah, more part of Hashem's Plan than His wanting nature and others' free will to hold even when they impact my life.

Comment: Nearly every rishon holds that hashgachah peratis is incomplete. The Ramban may be closest to universal HP, at least in some places he applies that everything that happens to people is the product of hashgachah. But the modern idea that even how a leaf falls in the forest is Providence appears to start with the Ramchal.

Comment: The truth is the Chassidish / Novhardok idea can coexist with the Chazon Ish's. I mean, they can't both be what the term "bitachon" means, but they are basically different topics. One is a descriptive attitude toward life -- living with the knowledge that everything that happens to you is "gam zu letovah" because it is to serve His Plan. The other is prescriptive, a way to succeed -- if you trust Hashem enough, your efforts will bear fruit, you will get the life you want. (How much effort? Rav Dessler writes -- the more bitachon, the less hishtadlus needed.)

Comment: But most people, even those who pay lip service to Chassidic bitachon, believe both. After all, many who trust G-d don't get what they want. How many holy people's lives ended in Auschwitz? (In fact, I think it's important to remember the CI wrote Emunah uBitachon just a few years after. It could be one of his points was to stop people from asking just that question about the martyrs.) And so you end up with "eventually you'll see how what you got was what made you happiest in the long run". Which brings us back to "Hashem's Plan", not "what you want".